# User friendly way to update content in mysql based website

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, article

My question i what the most user friendly way to manage content for a MYSQL based site?

I want an experience that is user friendly for anyone working on the site. There is allot of articles content that i need to add, while the existing content needs to get edited and updated regularly. I imagine there must be very user friendly ways/solutions/applications/plugins to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into any content management systems like Joomla, Wordpress? I have created numerous Joomla based websites and given access to users who had no knowledge of websites, databases. All they would do is log in and add/edit remove their content.

Comment: Thank you for ansering! I have but considering that the website is already constructed from scratch and based off the frontends interaction with my own self written phps on the server and mysql tables would there still be a way to integrate wordpress or joomla content managing / editor plugins into the setup?

Comment: Yes. You can modify/integrate your scripts/plugins.

Comment: well ive looked at wp plugins like edit any table but they are really very primitive , ie they dont even let me change the size of the entry fields , so editing articles in them is a real nuisance. any tips on what you would use in this scenario.